# Windows 7 + Oracle 9.2 + greek characters

Tags: oracle, odbc

I have a newly installed VM with windows 7 32 bit and I installed oracle 9.2 client. 
My application uses ODBC to connect to oracle through TNS names.
While connection is made greek characters appear as in a different character set.

My application works correctly on my win7 where I develop the software. Do I have to do something for the greek charsets?

Comment: when creating the database, what Encoding have you choosed?

Comment: I mean what character set...

Comment: EL8MSWIN1253 (I didn't set up the DB, but this is what I see)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it by adding an env variable

NLS_LANG=GREEK_GREECE.EL8MSWIN1253